# .htaccess URL needs to be created for sub folder view

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have enabled  `AllowOverride All` in Apache configuration file.

This the URL users are typing in browser

```
http://hostname/system_name/dynamic_text/login
```

This needs to be working as below

```
http://hostname/system_name/index.php?id=dynamic_text
```

I have created rewrite rule as below. But its not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z])$/login index.php?login=$1 [NC,L]
```

Can you suggest better way to fulfill this requirement

Comment: not sure what are you expecting for $1? where does it get the value?

Comment: @codekaizer yes. Need to get the dynamic_text value from this

Comment: If this .htaccess is inside `system_name/` then change your rule to: `RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/login/?$ index.php?login=$1 [QSA,NC,L]`

Comment: Where is the .htaccess located? Do you want to rewrite to `index.php?id=` or `index.php?login=`, which one is it? What have you done so far to debug this (like enabling rewrite logging an checking out what’s going on) …?

Comment: `[a-z]` will only target the chars `a` to `z`. `dynamic_text` has an underscore in it

Comment: thanks @anubhava. this is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with your regex pattern as `[a-z]` only matches a single lowercase letter. You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/login/?$ index.php?login=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: actually this rule in your above comment is working

*RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/login/?$ index.php?login=$1 [QSA,NC,L]*

Answer (score 0):

This is created as per answers and comments above and works for me as expected.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/login/?$ index.php?login=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```